# Settings for custom comma-first format in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

It's a little bit of a silly question, sorry. However I thought maybe someone else is accustomed to the same syntax as I'm using.

In IntelliJ, I'm trying to figure out if there is a setting (or how to adjust a settings) which would allow a default comma-first formatting (comma separated values as in example below). For me - it's mainly an issue with Scala and/or Java, but I think it's a general IntelliJ rule within "Code Style" section.

As an example, I've got accustomed to use the following syntax:

```
val opts = List(
    "a" -> "abc"
,   "b" -> "bdc"
,   "c" -> "cde"
)
```

But whenever this will get copy/pasted it would look like (and "Backspace" will move cursor on a line above):

```scala
val opts = List(
    "a" -> "abc"
    ,   "b" -> "bdc"
    ,   "c" -> "cde"
)
```

Or whenever you try to add a new option, the cursor will go under the option straight away ( as it's already assumed that comma is there, and "Backstace" returns you to a previous line ):

```scala
val opts = List(
    "a" -> "abc"
,   "b" -> "bdc"
,   "c" -> "cde"
    <CURSOR>
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help and any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 2 settings should alleviate some of the pain.

---

#### Fixing the indentation as a result of copy/paste

Change `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Reformat on Paste` to `Indent Block`. Here is the result:

[image]

Notice the different in indentation before and after.

---

#### Fixing the behaviour of the Enter and Backspace Key

Uncheck `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Smart Indent` for the `Enter` key. Here is the result:

[image]

**Caveat**: Note that these settings would apply to ALL code not just scala code and definitely not just for a specific Scala construct.